# How to get double precision values from UTF16-BE encoded data?

Tags: python

Kinda new to programming here.
I have a .data file that has values like "榿쾫䍥韛榿". It was saved in UTF-16-BE format.
I am trying to convert the characters into their actual double-precision value.

```
data=open('filename','r','UTF16-BE',errors='ignore')
val=data.read()
```

This is as far as  I can go. I've tried many modules(struct, codecs, NumPy) but haven't had any luck.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do those Chinese characters have to do with double-precision values?

Comment: Wht makes you think the data is UTF-16-BE? If you cannot explain what those Chinese (if that is what they are) characters have to do with double precision, then I suspect that what you have here is simply binary floating-point values.

Comment: The person who wrote the software for the experiment told me thats how it is encoded.

But, If it is simple binary floating point values what commands would work with that file?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of things that leave me puzzled: you put some Asian chars as example and then talk about their actual double-precision values; and your `open` statement will not work: it should be

```
data = open('filename', 'r', encoding='UTF-16-BE')
```

That apart, you're trying to read all the content of the file in a single variable, so you get everything, including the 2-bytes BOM at the beginning, the line separators, etc. You may want to loop on your data with

```
for line in data:
    print(line)    ## or do what you need to with that line
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The data from the measurements we did were saved in that format as Asian characters and some random symbols. I used the same file in matlab and it worked. I'm trying to replicate  that in python .

Comment: Ok, if you iterate over the lines as I suggested do you see your data?

Comment: When I try to open the file without using ''' errors='ignore' '''

I get an error,
'''utf-16-be' codec can't decode bytes in position 460-461: illegal UTF-16 surrogate'''

Comment: If you have an hex editor you can easily check if the file really is utf-16-be: the first two bytes must be `FE FF`. With the same tool you can also check which codes are at positions 460-461 - the error message tells you that those codes should represent a "surrogate" character but something is wrong with them. Anyhow opening the file with the `errors = "ignore" argument should allow you to read everything else